# Customize setting activity in android (preference)

Tags: android, xml, settings, preference

i  used template of Settings activity (preference) in android studio but i have this layout.[my XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPrV2.png)

but i want the layout look like this [new XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr2m5.png)

and i finished create the top bar"help" with photoshop, how to add the top bar "help" like my customize layout? Thx.

And this is my code (pref_headers.xml):

```
<header
    android:fragment="com.example.hp.refomandaapps.SettingsActivity$NotificationPreferenceFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_notifications" />

<header
    android:fragment="com.example.hp.refomandaapps.SettingsActivity$DataSyncPreferenceFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_sync_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_data_sync" />
```

Answer (score 1):

add this at the top .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="#000">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Title"
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:textSize="8.5pt"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i using default template from android studio which is the layout is created by R.xml.header not by R.layout.*example.
So i confused to modify layout from xml folder

Comment: create you custom layout why use Android stdio's layout .

Comment: because easier to make settings layout with android studio template (settings preference), but i cant modify the layout.

Comment: That's why i am saying . your deign is easy to make so make you own layout .